# Is $a^T M b = b^T M a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

I am trying to reproduce a proof and I'm stuck at one point where it looks like this :

$a^T M b + b^T M a = 2 a^T M b$

Therefore the only explanation I can get is this, if true :

is $a^T M b = b^T M a$ ? (Preferrably with an explanation or a linear algebra property)

Note : a and b are (dx1) vectors, and M is a (dxd) matrix.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Thanks for the answers, in my case, M is a symmetric covariance matrix.

Comment: Then yes, it is true.

Comment: If you want to thank the users for their answers, you may consider upvoting these answers and/or accept one of them.

Comment: @user1551 I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that $a^\intercal M b$ is a scalar, so $a^\intercal Mb=(a^\intercal Mb)^\intercal = b^\intercal M^\intercal a$. So the result is true if $M$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 3):

If $M$ is symmetric, yes, because $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ and $(A^T)^T=A$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes $a^TMb$ and $b^TMa$ are scalars, thus $(a^TMb)^T=a^TMb$, but using the rule that for two vectors $c,d$, $(c^Td)^T=d^Tc^{TT}=d^Tc$. we have:

$(a^TMb)^T=b^T(a^TM)^T=b^T(M^Ta)=b^TMa$.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the result could be false if $M$ is not assumed to be symmetric. You make a calculation mistake in the last equality.

Comment: Oh yes, i see, but these situations arise when in minimisation problems including symmetric matrices, (at least thats where I have seen this), so I think my mind just made an assumption there.

Comment: Everybody made the same assumption which holds for my question. I upvoted you back to zero :)

Comment: Thankyou! it frustrates me when there are downvotes for no reason

Comment: Well, it wasn't without a reason earlier, because the OP hadn't stated M was assumed to be symmetric, but now that it's been precisely stated, your answer makes perfect sense. (+1)

Comment: Yes, but originally, $M$ was not assumed to be symmetric, so your answer was simply false. The other two answers were correct from the beginning. Your answer only got correct once the OP changed the question.